# Gremlin Through java reading external JSON vertex and add to existing open graph gives Invalid vertex provided exception?

Tags: java, json, titan, gremlin

I am trying to read external JSON vertex and add it to exiting open titan graph. as follows:

```
gremlin> newVertex = graph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).reader().create().readVertex(new FileInputStream("/tmp/sample_vertex.json"),null);
gremlin> v[42092]
gremlin> existingVertex = graph.V(4145).next();
gremlin> v[4145]
gremlin> existingVertex.addEdge("has",newVertex);
Invalid vertex provided: v[42092]
```

I have already exported vertex using GraphSON.io as follows:

```
gremlin> graph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).writer().create().writeVertex(new FileInputStream("/tmp/sample_vertex.json"),g.V().next());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for `readVertex` looks like this:

```
Vertex readVertex(InputStream inputStream, Function<Attachable<Vertex>, Vertex> vertexAttachMethod)
```

If you supply a `null` to the `vertexAttachMethod`, then no attempt is made to attach the vertex to your graph and you just get an unattached `StarVertex` as the result. Consider this approach instead:

```
gremlin> graph = TinkerGraph.open()
==>tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0]
gremlin> g = graph.traversal()
==>graphtraversalsource[tinkergraph[vertices:0 edges:0], standard]
gremlin> start = graph.io(GraphSONIo.build()).reader().create().readVertex(new FileInputStream('v.json'), Attachable.Method.create(graph))
==>v[1]
gremlin> gremlin> g.V(start).as('start').
......1>   addV().as('end').
......2>   addE('has').from('start').to('end')
==>e[1][1-has->0]
```

Comment: Thanks For the answer. That worked for me.
but i am getting vertex without its " inE { } " and " outE { } ". is it that i have to re configure edges manually.? @stephen-mallette

Comment: If you need edges, then they too need to be attached. See the other overload of `readVertex` which has an `edgeAttachMethod`.

Comment: okay. I will try. One more thing for example, i exported 3 vertices which has edges between them to json which exports 3 different json vertex. and again i imported 3 exported vertices to other graph but problems is edges are not retained and through JAVA i implemented but in graph it actually does not existed. So do i need to commit after adding?

Comment: and adding vertex with `readVertex` will add new `id()` in graph vertex. and if we imported two vertices and there is edge between them how can overloaded `readVertex()` with `edgeAttachMethod` will create exact edge between them??

Comment: yes - you have to control commits yourself on calls to `readVertex`. the `edgeAttachMethod` is just a function. It takes an `Attachable<Edge>` as a parameter. The `Edge` is actually a `StarEdge` which should provide enough information for you to write a function to lookup the related vertices in the new graph and then write the edge and properties between them. You don't quite say what your use case is, but you might not find this method particularly "fast" depending on what you're doing.

Comment: okay. My use case actually is i want to export 3-4 vertices which is having edges between them to one `JSON` file. So that i can import and reconfigure that same 3-4 vertices and edges in other graph or same graph if i lost. 
currently i am doing like exporting each vertex to separate `JSON` file and importing one by one and manually adding edges between them. 
problem is i have to write complicated edges logic to reconfigure edges and make those vertices as they were previously in graph.

Comment: well, if that's your use case then i would probably not try to use `readVertex` in that way. i don't know that there is an easy way to do what you're asking - you already mention the challenges in doing it. I will say that the use case doesn't sound like one I've ever run into before. It's not clear to me as to why you would need to do something like that. I'm not sure why vertices/edges would become "lost" from a graph.

Comment: Actually thing is, as two users have separate graphs and lets say user 1 wants object having 3-4 vertices and edges between them from user2 graph. so i am exporting user two graph object having 3-4 vertices and edges associated with it. and importing to user1 graph.

Comment: I see. Well - I imagine you're stuck with the complexities of migrating a subgraph between graphs then. I would just write some code to handle dealing with that I think.

Comment: right.! so ya i am handling with writing the code to maintain. well thanks for all your answers and support.